# Stationary phase for retarded potentials in electromagnetism

Tags: greens-function, stationary-point, oscillatory-integral

I want to apply something like a stationary phase approximation to the following expression

$\int_V d^3x' \frac{B(x')}{|x-x'|}e^{ik|x-x'|}$

with $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$, $k\rightarrow \infty$ and $B$ is slowly varying function over the Volume $V$.

For better clearness one can assume the volume $V$ to be a finite box $V=[0,L_x]\times [0,L_y]\times [0,L_z]$ and one can for example assume $B=\sin(\pi x/L_x)^2\sin(\pi y/L_y)^2\sin(\pi z/L_z)^2$, where $L_{x,y,z}\gg \frac{2\pi}{k}$.

My problem is that I cannot apply the standard method for stationary phases, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation because my function $g=\frac{B(x')}{|x-x'|}$ is not smooth at $x=x'$ and the phase function $f=|x-x'|$ is not differentiable at $x=x'$...

The answer to my question at lowest order should be

$\int_V d^3x' \frac{B(x')}{|x-x'|}e^{ik|x-x'|}=-\frac{4\pi}{k^2}B(x)$, but I don't know how to show that rigorously...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Are you also looking for a formula for $x$ outside of the volume? If not, and you are looking for $x$ inside the volume, then you will get reasonable formulas of the type you describe only if your integrand falls off with $1/|x-x'|^3$.

Comment: Hi, inside the Volume $x\in V$. I think your assumption is fulfilled, because sin falls off with $1/x^2$ to the boundray of my volume $V$. Can you explain how you came to this statement?

Comment: Ok, if you transform to spherical coordinates such that $r = |x-x'|$ you will get an extra $r^2$ from the volume element and you will have $\sim B r e^{ikr}$ in your integrand. However, if you have start with $B e^{ik|x-x'|}/|x-x'|^3$ in your integrand and transform to spherical coordinates you get $\sim B e^{ikr}/r$, the real part of which will integrate exactly to $\sim B(x)$ as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not written like that. One just has $\int_V d^3x' \frac{B(x')}{|x-x'|}e^{ik|x-x'|}$. But the result has to be $\sim B(x)$ in the limit of large $k$. I checked this by evaluating the integral numerically for many points.